# Flex 3 Database, XML & SEO Strategy

Tags: xml, apache-flex, seo

I've got a Flex 3 website that pulls questions and answers from a database.

I want to improve my site's SEO. If I take my database info and put it in an XML file in the web root, would this improve the SEO?

I want to continue using my database. I don't want to re-write the site to work with XML. The XML would simply sit in the webroot, but otherwise would be unconnected to the way my site actually works.

It would have the same information as in my database, so I'm not doing anything slimy. The problem is that Google doesn't access the database when it crawls the site, and this is where almost all of my site's content resides.

a) Would this violate any Google policy?
b) Would this work?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: Hi don't have a clear answer for ya but you can start looking here: kind of old posts as well and I know Adobe acquired Omniture a while back so I imagine they are working to fix this problem, but it is a deep issue for some companies, I think the general theme is either the site is 100% flash and people will find it because of the domain like hbo.com or other content found outside of the Flash displayed info, please post back if you make progress. http://joshblog.net/2007/08/03/make-your-rich-internet-application-seo-friendly/

Comment: Hi shaunhusain, Thank you for the message and the link. Yeah, I'm kinda screwed. My site is all Flash and I'm not HBO, so I'm trying to find  solution, however imperfect, to improve my SEO.

Answer (score 2):

a) Would this violate any Google policy?
no

b) Would this work?
no

what you need for SEO success you need a site that has - as a minimum requirement -

- A) a Startpage
- B) a Sitemap (XML, see sitemaps.org)
- C) Landingpages

the XML file with a database dump is neither A, B or C. it is just a big file with some content that is not even targeted for human users.

i would recommend taking a step back and think about your site in generall: what page can i offer people if they search for [your targeted search term here]? and then start to implement these pages.

p.s.: please check out https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ for SEO questions

Comment: A site map can be created for flex using swfaddress.
http://insideria.com/2010/09/adding-deeplinking-and-analyti.html

Comment: Hi Franz, Thank you for your message. I'm not sure how I can apply a startpage, sitemap, or landingpage to a Flex site. Flex sites are in effect, pageless.

Comment: Another idea. What's a simple way to add load the XML content into the noscript tag? Can anyone point me to an example? Thank you.

Comment: that's the part, you can only search engine optimize pages, not apps. in this case i would treat the flex-app as the product and build (information) landing pages (i.e.: blog, FAQ, an HTML site with the database content) around it, with a conversion element to the flex-app. (noscript does not work (cloaking), but you can make a single not missleading HTML page below the app)

Comment: Hi Franz, Thank you for the good ideas. You right. App and SEO are a problem. If I put an HTML site in the noscript will Google consider it cloaking? I didn't quite understand what you meant by an HTML page "below the app". Do you mean have a link in the app to an HTML version of the app? Thanks so much. www.brainpinata.com

Comment: if you add an HTML site in the noindex google will see it, but will not count it as content (it's not cloaking, just not working, trust me, i tried). but you can have an HTML site, but if your browser supports flash and javascript layer the flash app above it (as long as its not missleading, it works) ... note: you will still have only one site, which is not very much from a seo perspective.